# TypeORM / Postgres - Include all in relation where at least one meets requirement

Tags: postgresql, subquery, relation, typeorm

I am very new to SQL/TypeORM in general and I'm currently facing a problem where I want to load match participants related to a match where at least one participant has a passed userId. The query could be thought of as "Load all my matches with my opponents". I have three tables:

public.match << OneToMany >> public.match_participant << ManyToOne >> public.user

So far I have gone about doing:

```
select * from public.match m
left join public.match_participant mp on mp."matchId" = m.id
left join public.user u on u.id = mp."userId"
where u.id = 3
```

and in typeORM

```
    repository
      .createQueryBuilder('match')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('match.participants', 'participants')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('participants.user', 'user')
      .where('user.id=:id')
      .setParameter('id', 1)
      .getMany();
```

Which of course loads all matches, participants and users for that particular userId but other participants are not included. I believe something like a "subquery" could be of use but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```select * from match match 
join (select p."matchId" from public.match_participant p 
   where p."userId" = 1) selfMatch on (selfMatch."matchId" = match.id)
join match_participant mp on (mp."matchId" = match.id)
left join public.user u on mp."userId" = u.id
```

This seems to be somewhat what I need but I don't know how to convert it into typeORM

Answer (score 2):

After a bunch of trial and error I learned how to convert a pure query to the builder. The solution was the following:

```
matchRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('match')
      .innerJoin(
        query => {
          return query
            .from(MatchParticipant, 'p')
            .select('p."matchId"')
            .where('p."userId" = :id');
        },
        'selfMatch',
        '"selfMatch"."matchId" = match.id',
      )
      .leftJoinAndSelect('match.participants', 'participants')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('participants.user', 'user')
      .setParameter('id', id)
      .getMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need the query builder for this.

```js
@Entity()
class Match {
  @OneToMany(...)
  participants: MatchParticipant[];
}

@Entity()
class MatchParticipant {
  @ManyToOne(...)
  match: Match;

  @ManyToOne(...)
  participant: Participant;
}

@Entity()
class User {
  @OneToMany(...)
  matches: MatchParticipant[];
}

// ...

repository.manager.find(MatchParticipant, { where: { match: { participants: { participant: { id } } } } });
```

Comment: Well I needed to load the associated User as well. So Match + Participants where one meets requirement + Users associated with each participant